# Shredding an external HDD

Tags: security, external-hdd, shred

How do I shred the data on an  external HDD? I am trying `shred "/media/me/New Volume/"` but I get `failed to open for writing: Is a directory`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run `shred` on the device, not on the mount point.

Type `mount` and get the device name (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`, likely it will be `/dev/sdXY` where X is a letter and Y is a number), then unmount it (run `umount /your/device`) and run `shred /your/device`.

Answer (score 1):

`shred` runs on block devices or files.

So it is either (if `/dev/sdx` is your external HDD):

```
shred -n 1 /dev/sdx
```

Or, in case of a file (if the filesystem is 2TiB large):

```
truncate -s 2T "/media/me/New Volume/shredfile"
shred -n 1 "/media/me/New Volume/shredfile"
sync
rm "/media/me/New Volume/shredfile"
```

The file will not shred the entire HDD, just the free space in the filesystem.

The option `-n 1` makes sure `shred` uses only a single pass - multiple passes are a waste of time.